# how to get a particular field value from map object using java

Tags: java

> I am trying to set manufacture price code  ,that value is in my map
> object but when I want to get getName() from map object I am not able
> to get that particular value. If I use

```
ipcToMFPNameMap.getClass().getName()
```

> this line of code to get particular value I get "java.util.HashMap" in
>
> > my manufacture price code filed for your reference I post my code what I tried to  get the particular result

```
private Item getItemManufacturerPriceCodes(Item item) {
          List<ItemPriceCode> itemPriceCodes = item.getItemPriceCodes();
          List<String> priceCodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (ItemPriceCode ipc : itemPriceCodes) {
              //get the string value from the list
               priceCodeList.add(ipc.getPriceCode());
        }
          //pass this string value in query
          List<ManufacturerPriceCodes>mpc = manufacturerPriceCodesRepository.
                 findByManufacturerIDAndPriceCodeInAndRecordDeleted(item.getManufacturerID(),priceCodeList,NOT_DELETED);
          
          //Convert list to map
          Map<String, ManufacturerPriceCodes> ipcToMFPNameMap = mpc.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(ManufacturerPriceCodes :: getPriceCode,Function.identity()));// Object



         for (ItemPriceCode ipcs : itemPriceCodes) {
              ipcs.setManufacturerPriceCode(ipcToMFPNameMap.getClass().getName());
        }
          item.getItemPriceCodes()
          .removeIf(ipcs -> DELETED.equals(ipcs.getRecordDeleted()));
      return item;      
      }
```

> I got this type of Result
> [image]

> But I want this this type of Result
> [image]

> I get issue exact at this point

```
ipcs.setManufacturerPriceCode(ipcToMFPNameMap.getClass().getName());
```

> my manufacture price code is a string type

Comment: Why did you use `ipcToMFPNameMap.getClass().getName()` in the first place? Why did you assume `getClass()` returns a map __key__ not the __class__ of the object (a map in this case)?

Comment: ipcToMFPNameMap is my map Object and I want to get manufacture price code from it and store it

Comment: Did you not think you would have to pass the price code to the map in order to get the manufacturerPriceCode for _that particular price code_?

Answer (score 0):

Your Map contains `ManufacturerPriceCodes` objects keyed on their `priceCode` which is defined as a String.  So you can get the name of an item in the Map as follows (where `priceCode` is a String).

```
String manufacturerPriceCodesName = ipcToMFPNameMap.get(priceCode).getName();
```

The `ManufacturerPricesCodes` appears to capture the price code as a String but `Item` has a `List<ItemPriceCode>`.  You'll have to figure out how to map back and forth.

Comment: String manufacturerPriceCodesName = ipcToMFPNameMap.get(priceCode).getName(); if do this way I got error 500 internal server error

Comment: The 500 is an HTTP error code.  The code snippet in question assumes that `priceCode` is a String and that `ipcToMFPNameMap` is a Map.  This is not making an HTTP request..  If you are deploying this code to a server and calling it and it returned 500 then you need to review the server log to try to get more insight.